# Connection between logit model and power law distribution

Tags: ordered-logit, power-law

I am wondering whether it is appropriate to make a connection between the use of a logit model and a power law distribution.
My dependent variable is categorical and ordinal, therefore I am fitting a logit model.

Moreover, it was found that my dependent variable follows a power law distribution. Could I therefore create a link between the distribution of my dependent variable and the choice of my model (compared to the alternative of using a probit  model)?

I thought about arguing that compared to a probit model, a logit model may be more appropriate due to the assumed error distribution (extreme value type 1). However, I am afraid that I confuse several different concepts here so I would appreciate some more insights on my thought. 
In previous discussions on this platform I found that "Logit is better in the case of extreme independent variables" but also it is always argued that probit and logit predictions are very similar.

Thank you very much already in advance.